# 3D geometric topology (e.g. intersection) in Python

Tags: python, geometry, geos

I am using GEOS ([in Python/Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/)) to manipulate some 3d elements. All topological operations work perfectly in 2D. So, I created a simple `MultiPolygon` with 3D polygons (very simple in fact, it is just a collection of vertical planes), and a `LineString` which is also 3D. Now I simply wanted the intersection of those (which I believe would have been a list of 3D-points) :

```
>>> l = LineString([0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1])
>>> p = Polygon([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1000], [1, 0, 1000], [1, 0, 0]])
>>> p.intersects(l)
False
```

So OK, geos doesn't support topological operations with 3D-data ... Well, there must be lots of libraries out there that can do that for me right ??? So I googled, and I just can't find a single one !!! So if somebody has a pointer, that would be great ...

**EDIT**

There is a similar question as [Intersections of 3D polygons in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549708/intersections-of-3d-polygons-in-python), but this doesn't give any satisfying answer (see comment).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersections of 3D polygons in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549708/intersections-of-3d-polygons-in-python)

Comment: @plaes: Except that [Intersections of 3D polygons in python] doesn't have any good answer. They suggest using pvtrace, which traces some rays : I remind you that I'm using `MultiPolygons` and `LineString` : it will be very unefficient to iterate through all polygons, all segments of line and calculate polygon INTER segment for each of those.

Comment: plus, just go to pvtrace's site, and look for the doc, and then tell me if you'd like to use it ...

Comment: Well, tell me first what should the result of intersection between 3D object and a line be?

Comment: A collection of 3D points and 3D lines. Is this a test ?

Comment: Yeah, though closing issue was my mistake (just trying to help keeping things clean).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't believe that there is a single "good choice" of a library to do this in python, but a number of promising projects are in the works, foremost amongst them improved [cgal-bindings](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/) on google code.

The new licensing conditions of CGAL from version 4 onward (GPL/LGPL) also make some parts of the original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549708/intersections-of-3d-polygons-in-python) on this topic out of date.